# Transpose data from rows to columns in MySQL (without any aggregation)

Tags: mysql

I need to transpose data from rows to columns in MySQL but without any aggregation.

For example, I have the following Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `MyTable` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,`city` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , 
`category` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `item`VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `price` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL , 
`date` DATE NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

with the following data:

```
INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`id`, `city`, `category`, `item`, `price`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, 'A', 'Cat1','It1', '10.00', '2018-01-01'), 
(NULL, 'A', 'Cat1','It1', '20.00', '2018-01-02'), 
(NULL, 'A', 'Cat1','It2', '30.00', '2018-01-03'),
(NULL, 'A', 'Cat2','It1', '40.00', '2018-01-04'),
(NULL, 'B', 'Cat1','It1', '50.00', '2018-01-05'),
(NULL, 'A', 'Cat1', 'It1', '100.00', '2018-02-11'), 
(NULL, 'A', 'Cat1','It1', '200.00', '2018-02-12'), 
(NULL, 'A', 'Cat1','It2', '300.00', '2018-02-13'),
(NULL, 'A', 'Cat2','It1', '400.00', '2018-02-14'),
(NULL, 'B', 'Cat1','It1', '500.00', '2018-02-15')
```

When I use this query

```
 SELECT city, category, item, sum(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) = "201801" 
THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS "Jan", sum(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) = "201802" 
THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS "Feb" FROM MyTable WHERE 1 GROUP BY city, category, item
```

then I get aggregated result for 'Item1':

[image]

But I need all transactions without any aggregation:
[image]

How should I compose the query in order to get the right result?

Comment: If somebody posts his homework with constrained requirements; the least we expect from him/her is to not use images. Instead, give `CREATE TABLE` statements in formatted text, as well as expected output. So, that we can easily reproduce your problem statement. A SQL Fiddle or DB fiddle would be bonus. Help us if you want help.

Comment: @ Madhur Bhaiya thanks for your comment. I made the corrections.

Comment: Please refrain from ping-spamming. Thanks.

Comment: @Kirill consider handing data display related requirements in your application code (eg: PHP, C++, Java etc). MySQL query will be extremely verbose for this, and a generic solution is not possible when more months are included.

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general class of what you are trying to do is called a **PIVOT**.  In a PIVOT, subsets of rows act like tables, in the sense that the data from a single column gets divvied up into several columns.  `JOIN` can help you here:

```
SELECT
  tblItems.city, tblItems.category, tblItems.item,
  tblJan.price AS Jan,
  tblFeb.price AS Feb
FROM
  (SELECT city, category, item
   FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY city, category, item) AS tblItems
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT city, category, item, price
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) = "201801") AS tblJan
ON (tblItems.city = tblJan.city AND tblItems.category = tblJan.category AND tblItems.item = tblJan.item)
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT city, category, item, price
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) = "201802") AS tblFeb
ON (tblItems.city = tblFeb.city AND tblItems.category = tblFeb.category AND tblItems.item = tblFeb.item)
ORDER BY tblItems.city, tblItems.category, tblItems.item;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f77978a/3

**However**, your very next question is going to be: "How can I do this dynamically, If I don't know ahead of time how many sub-tables I will have?"  In the case at hand, it might not matter, because there are a fixed number of months in a year.  But sooner or later, you are going to want to perform a PIVOT dynamically.

Some RDBMSes have a built-in `PIVOT` function, but unfortunately, MySQL isn't one of them.  So, for MySQL, you need logic to dynamically build the PIVOT query, and then execute the built query.  That logic can be either in a stored procedure within MySQL, or in an external language that has library functions for MySQL (most modern languages do).

EDIT: Or, you can consider following the comment from @Madhur Bhaiya, and delegate the *display* of the information to the program that fetches the data from your database; SQL is powerful, but -- as with everything else -- it's not the right place to answer all your needs.